# Where is the asmx service client(web reference) to WCF client Service reference how to reference

Tags: web-services, wcf, asmx

So I am going through and updating some old web service client code and I am trying to figure how to update some of the features of the asmx client setup stuff to the WCF standard...

for instance these line of code...

```
service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 180;
service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(sectoken);
```

where the sectoken is a Microsoft.Web.Services2 UsernameToken...

```
sectoken = new UsernameToken(credential.UserName, credential.Password, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
```

And the credential is a System.Net.NetworkCredential.

What is the equivalent in WCF?  Doing some googling, It looks like you should set up a OperationContextScop at which point it looks like you can add a timestamp and token...  But I am not sure what is happening when you do that?  What is an OperationContextScope?  It has been mentioned on Microsoft's site, but I am loathed to admit that I am not sure if it applies to my circumstance...

Also how would one set the service.url?  I tried something like this...

```
service.Endpoint.ListenUri = new Uri(config.getAttribute("serviceEndpoint"));
```

That would seem like it would work,  but again I am not certain...

They then Overload the the Soap Service Client...

```
SoapMessageFilter.OverloadSoapServiceClient(service);
```

What would the equivalent be in WCF???

Again, there is plenty of information about each of those pieces out on the internet, but nothing concisely explains how to upgrade that functionality if migrating from ASMX client services to WCF client services.

Comment: That's not ASMX. That's WSE,, specifically WSE 2.0. It's extremely ancient. There may not be a one to one mapping to WCF, as WSE was developed before the standards were finalized.

Comment: BTW, that's why you may not find a "how to". You shouldn't be migrating - you should be rewriting.

Comment: Let me clarify, the client node is set up using a web reference, not a service reference in visual studio.  Consider this a rewrite.  I want to clear our code of all the wse references and all the asmx endpoints.  That being said, they are generating most of the settings in code and not through configurations etc.  I am trying to find out the definitive equivalents of the above statements.  I guess my only option is to experiment.  I didn't realize you lost points for being polite btw.  Ill keep that in mind.

Comment: What do you mean lost points for being polite?